# TimerTrigger Schedules and code execution time

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

What happens if a function gets invoked by a TimerTigger every 5 minutes and for some reasons the code takes more than 5 minutes to complete?

- Does this result in my function running twice at the same time?
- Or does the interval start when the triggered code execution is completed?

I could not find an answer myself in the docs.
I have to ensure that my function is running always as singleton.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: posible related with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542705/what-happens-when-a-scheduled-webjob-runs-for-a-long-time take a look, al webjobs works in the same way inside trigger, azure scheduler,etc. either way you can make a test loggind data and insert some long Sleep/ThreadWait and then review the azure webjob log in azure portal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your function execution takes longer than the timer interval, another execution won't be triggered until after the current invocation completes. The next execution is scheduled **after** the execution completes. You can see this in the code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs#L150). You can prove this to yourself by trying a simple local example - create a function that runs every 5 seconds, and put a sleep in there for a minute. You won't see another function start until the first finishes.

As far as running singleton, the above shows that only a single function invocation runs at a given time on the **same instance (VM)**. The SDK further ensures that no other functions are running **across scaled out instances**. You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger). To see this in action, you can simulate by starting two instances of your console app locally - one will run the schedule the other will not. However, if you kill the one running the schedule, the other one will pick it up after a short time (within a minute).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer

Comment: If this answers your question fully, please mark it as the accepted answer so others know, thanks.