# What happens to running processes on a continuous Azure WebJob when website is redeployed?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've read about graceful shutdowns [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VMgLAWjF-PY) using the WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE and [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#graceful) using Cancellation Tokens, so I understand the premise of graceful shutdowns, however I'm not sure how they will affect WebJobs that are in the middle of processing a queue message.

So here's the scenario:

1. I have a WebJob with functions listening to queues.
2. Message is added to Queue and job begins processing.
3. While processing, someone pushes to develop, triggering a redeploy.

Assuming I have my WebJobs hooked up to deploy on git pushes, this deploy will also trigger the WebJobs to be updated, which (as far as I understand) will kick off some sort of shutdown workflow in the jobs. So I have a few questions stemming from that.

1. Will jobs in the middle of processing a queue message finish processing the message before the job quits? Or is any shutdown notification essentially treated as "this bitch is about to shutdown. If you don't have anything to handle it, you're SOL."
2. If we are SOL, is our best option for handling shutdowns essentially to wrap anything you're doing in the equivalent of DB transactions and implement your shutdown handler in such a way that all changes are rolled back on shutdown?
3. If a queue message is in the middle of being processed and the WebJob shuts down, will that message be requeued? If not, does that mean that my shutdown handler needs to handle requeuing that message?
4. Is it possible for functions listening to queues to grab any more queue messages after the Job has been notified that it needs to shutdown?

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated! Also, if anyone has any other useful links on how to handle job shutdowns besides the ones I mentioned, it would be great if you could share those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After no small amount of testing, I think I've found the answers to my questions and I hope someone else can gain some insight from my experience.

NOTE: All of these scenarios were tested using .NET Console Apps and Azure queues, so I'm not sure how blobs or table storage, or different types of Job file types, would handle these different scenarios.

1. After a Job has been marked to exit, the triggered functions that are running will have the configured amount of time (grace period) (5 seconds by default, but I think that is [configurable by using a settings.job file](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VMgLAWjF-PY)) to finish before they are exited.  If they do not finish in the grace period, the function quits.  Main() (or whichever file you declared host.RunAndBlock() in), however, will finish running any code after `host.RunAndBlock()` for up to the amount of time remaining in the grace period (I'm not sure how that would work if you used an infinite loop instead of RunAndBlock). As far as handling the quit in your functions, you can essentially "listen" to the CancellationToken that you can pass in to your triggered functions for IsCancellationRequired and then handle it accordingly. Also, you are not SOL if you don't handle the quits yourself. Huzzah! See point #3.
2. While you are not SOL if you don't handle the quit (see point #3), I do think it is a good idea to wrap all of your jobs in transactions that you won't commit until you're absolutely sure the job has ran its course. This way if your function exits mid-process, you'll be less likely to have to worry about corrupted data. I can think of a couple scenarios where you might want to commit transactions as they pass (batch jobs, for instance), however you would need to structure your data or logic so that previously processed entities aren't reprocessed after the job restarts.
3. You are not in trouble if you don't handle job quits yourself.  My understanding of what's going on under the covers is virtually non-existent, however I am quite sure of the results. If a function is in the middle of processing a queue message and is forced to quit before it can finish, HAVE NO FEAR! When the job grabs the message to process, it will essentially hide it on the queue for a certain amount of time. If your function quits while processing the message, that message will "become visible" again after x amount of time, and it will be re-grabbed and ran against the potentially updated code that was just deployed.
4. So I have about 90% confidence in my findings for #4. And I say that because to attempt to test it involved quick-switching between windows while not actually being totally sure what was going on with certain pieces.  But here's what I found: on the off chance that a queue has a new message added to it in the grace period b4 a job quits, I THINK one of two things can happen: If the function doesn't poll that queue before the job quits, then the message will stay on the queue and it will be grabbed when the job restarts.  However if the function DOES grab the message, it will be treated the same as any other message that was interrupted: it will "become visible" on the queue again and be reran upon the restart of the job.

That pretty much sums it up.  I hope other people will find this useful. Let me know if you want any of this expounded on and I'll be happy to try. Or if I'm full of it and you have lots of corrections, those are probably more welcome!

Comment: Good effort. This is kinda related to the question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042485/what-happens-to-in-progress-jobs-when-you-deploy-a-webjob

Comment: Indeed it is. That's definitely consistent with my findings, but it's nice to see an actual technical explanation of what's happening behind the scenes. I wouldn't mind seeing that explicitly documented somewhere, though, that's for sure!

Comment: Currently confused about the best way to handle this scenario - suspect I need to make all Q functions idempotent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164414/azure-webjob-graceful-shutdown-of-a-queue-handling-function